# Installing Bower in webstorm

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I just need to know the process of installing bower with webstorm. I am using 11.0.2 version. I have package.json file and I need to include bower.json to perform date-picker in angular.js. To do that, I need to install bower. In the git-hub, bower install angular-daterangepicker --save. But before this, I need to install bower right. Pls help me to do this..

https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

Answer (score 0):

Why not to install it with npm?

```
npm install bower --save-dev
```

Comment: Bower should really be installed globally, as it is a command line utility, not a project component. See http://bower.io/#install-bower

Answer (score 0):

To install bower globally so you can access it from everywhere on your pc, just install it using NPM:
`npm install bower -g`

http://bower.io/#install-bower